# Kill all processes by command

Tags: linux

I accumulate a lot of "ssh-agent -s" throughout my day due to ssh'ing to various servers. Here is my output from `ps aux`:

[image: output]

Is there a command I can write to kill all the processes with the command "ssh-agent -s"?

Comment: `killall` perhaps?

Comment: `killall "ssh-agent -s"
No matching processes belonging to you were found`

Comment: `man killall` before you go on a murder spree. You can only match the `ssh-agent` part.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ps aux | grep 'ssh-agent -s' | awk '{print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Slight error with the command. I think it should be ```ps aux | grep 'ssh-agent -s' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9```. There's a problem with the ' being before the }